# MultiLabelBinarizer returning Null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, nlp

Hi have an IMDB dataset which I'll be using for NLP. It contains a column with a movie's genre, but a movie can be classified as multiple genres:

df:

| movie | genre | review | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "movie 1" | [Drama, Action] | "This movie really...." | 3 |
| "movie 2" | [Horror, Thriller] | "In this truly fascinating, dark...." | 7 |
| "movie 3" | [Romance, Drama, Action] | "A good film, and one I'll watch...." | 9 |
| "movie 4" | [Adventure] | "Blah blah...." | 2 |
| "movie 5" | [Thriller, Suspense] | "blah blah blah...." | 5 |

I used the multilabel binarizer to essentially encode the genres and create a sparse matrix:

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

encoded_genres = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['genres']), columns=mlb.classes_)
encoded_genres.head()
```

My goal is to then merge it back to my original dataframe in order to pass it through ML models later:

```
df= df.join(encoded_genres).drop(columns='genres')
movies.head()
```

The problem (which I only learnt after trying to run a GridSearch) is that after merging, my dataframe now contains nulls values (specifically 40 in each genre column). Is there something wrong with my join that's causing me to suddenly get nulls? I confirmed that there were no nulls in my dataset before my attempt to merge.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, some errors in your question that you should fix:

- In your DataFrame you have a columns "genre" and then in your code you try to access column "genres", in plural.
- In your final piece of code you have `movies.head()`, which you haven't defined.
- You should add an example of the incorrect dataframe with null values that you are getting, so the problem can be fully understood. I assume that when you talk about null values you mean pandas NaNs.

With that being said, I have an intuition that it could be some problem with your initial dataframe (`df`) indexes. If the indexes of `df` and `encoded_genres` don't match, you will then have NaN rows in the indexes that don't match.

Please, add an example or screenshot of the initial dataframe (`df`) and the dataframe you are getting after the merge so you can be helped.